# Partial output with task scheduler and cscript

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, task, wsh, at-job

I have a bat file that I use as a wrapper to run
multiple vbs scripts with cscript and append its output to 
dated logfiles, when I click this bat file it works flawlessly.

But when I schedule it with Task Scheduler or At: I only get partial output
in the log files. Following is the wrapper

```
SET SERVER=\\server\share
SET TOOLOC=c:\Tools
REM need to pad hours with less than 2 digits eg: smaller than 10
SET datestamp=%date:~-4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%
SET timestamp=%datestamp%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%

echo %timestamp% >> %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-MEM_%datestamp%.log
cscript //NoLogo %TOOLOC%\memusage.vbs >> %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-MEM_%datestamp%.log 2>&1
echo %timestamp% >> %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-DISKS_%datestamp%.log
cscript //NoLogo %TOOLOC%\diskusage.vbs >>  %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-DISKS_%datestamp%.log 2>&1

echo %timestamp% >> %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-CPU_%datestamp%.log
cscript //NoLogo %TOOLOC%\cpusage.vbs >> %SERVER%\%COMPUTERNAME%-CPU_%datestamp%.log 2>&1
```

When I click it I get full output like this

```
20140322135937 
[C:]
free=20,17 GB
used=24,73 GB
total=44,90 GB

[M:]
free=4110,56 GB
used=4193,54 GB
total=8304,10 GB

[X:]
free=4110,56 GB
used=4193,54 GB
total=8304,10 GB
```

But when I let task scheduler or at run it I only get this
piece:

```
20140322134300 
[C:]
free=20,17 GB
used=24,73 GB
total=44,90 GB
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the `diskusage.vbs` code? The "problem" is probably in it, not in the batch file.

Comment: I doubt it, since it works If I click it manually. But here is a link to it http://pastebin.ca/2673532.

Comment: Sorry, but it seems that the only way mapped drives (and here i'm assuming it is what your M: and X: are), and scheduled tasks can work together is to explicitly create the mapping from the task. The recomended way of accessing network elements from background tasks (services or scheduled tasks) is to use unc paths. But i have not found a way to retrieve the space usage from vbs. All working code i have found uses `GetDiskFreeSpaceEx` api.

Comment: D'oh, You're absolutely right. I apologize for doubting you.
The other script: cpusage.vbs also broke with the wrapper, and I wrongly assumed the issues were related. Again  I'm sorry and Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

What user account does it run with as a scheduled task? I'm guessing it is scheduled with the `SYSTEM` user account which will not have access to network drives.

To fix, go to the properties of your scheduled task and change the user account to one that will have access to the network drives.

Comment: It runs under the same user account as I. It writes stuff to the network file just not everything I would suspect. Only a piece of it.